# How to create new View Controller in a standard way (Not overlapped view controller)

Tags: viewcontroller

I have a button (Button 1) and when I press it, I want to jump to my other View Controller (red) as "full-screen". But every time it shows me the new View Controller (red) as an overlapping view (with a space at the top). How can I show the new View Controller as a "full-screen" View Controller?

If I didn't follow any rules I am sorry. I hope for your help. Thank you very much.

Best regards

MacBook Pro: macOs Catalina 10.15.4
Xcode: Version 11.4

[Now my new view controller (red) is with space at the top when I reach it from the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeBQy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Select the second View Controller(Red). In its attribute inspector, there is an option called **Presentation** which is initially **automatic** selected. Make it Fullscreen.

Comment: Hello StrangeMan, meanwhile I found this solution by trying. Anyway thank you very much for your answer.